# Strongswan ikev2: https stops working on client when connected to vpn server

Tags: vpn, https, ssl-certificate, ipsec, strongswan

I have set up strongswan 5.3.3-1 on OpenWRT 15.05 based router.
Followed this [tutorial](https://hub.zhovner.com/geek/universal-ikev2-server-configuration/)

The certificate for Server side authentication is issued by Let's Encrypt - I use it for my synology box and it works fine.

Clients are authenticated using username/password (EAP-MSCHAPv2)

**/etc/ipsec.conf:**

```
config setup
    uniqueids=no
    charondebug ="all"

conn %default
    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=35s
    dpdtimeout=2000s

    keyexchange=ikev2
    auto=add
    rekey=no
    reauth=no
    fragmentation=yes
    eap_identity=%identity

    # left - local (server) side
    left=%any
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    leftauth=pubkey
    leftcert=le.cert.pem
    leftsendcert=always
    leftfirewall=yes

    # right - remote (client) side
    right=%any
    rightsourceip=10.7.0.0/24
    rightdns=192.168.1.1,192.168.1.254
    rightsendcert=never

conn ikev2-mschapv2
    rightauth=eap-mschapv2

conn ikev2-mschapv2-apple
    rightauth=eap-mschapv2
    leftid=@server.ddns.net
```

**/etc/strongswan.conf:**

```
charon {
        load_modular = yes
    plugins {
            include strongswan.d/charon/*.conf
        }
}

include strongswan.d/*.conf
```

When connecting to VPN from macbook client, I notice the following:

- traffic goes through the tunnel (as expected) - external ip is the public ip of VPN server
- dns works as expected - I can query by names all my internal machines on left (VPN server) site.
- ping to google.com works as well.

But in browser I can not connect to any https website.

The error I get in Chrome:

[image]

Firefox returns this:

[image]

This never happened to me with openvpn servers..
Any ideas what causes this issue with certificates?